# MPI running only one process

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I tried to run my hello.py:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
print "hello world from process ", rank
```

Using:

```
mpiexec  -n 5 python  hello.py
```

Obtaining:

```
hello world from process  0
hello world from process  0
hello world from process  0
hello world from process  0
hello world from process  0
```

I believe something is wrong with my config. Any ideas?

Comment: Ca you try `mpiexec -n 5 python -m mpi4py helloworld` and see what's the output?

Comment: don't you need to invoke `MPI_Init()` first ?
if not, this kind of error typically occurs when you are mixing two MPI implementations (for example your app is linked with Open MPI, but you invoke mpiexec from MPICH)

Comment: @gilles-gouaillardet `Init()` is called when MPI is imported from mpi4py. Python linked with another MPI implementation is indeed very likely. Jose, could you please post what `mpiexec --version` returns.

Comment: To check which implementation python is using try `MPI.get_vendor()`.

Comment: Always specify which MPI implementation you are using.